# Error accessing tail->prev

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I'm building a function which creates a doubly-linked queue, and I have to be able to traverse the list, increment down each node's data until it reaches zero or the condition is met. For some reason, when I run the queueTotal function, when the last node's amount = 0, and it goes to the else function in queueTotal, I get a segfault. I imagine that it's because I'm trying to access tail->prev and it was never declared. So how can I access the prev node?

isEmpty():

```
bool List::isEmpty() { 
    return head == 0;
}
```

Class constructor:

```
List::List() {
    head=0;
    tail=0;
}
```

overloading =:

```
List::Node* List::operator= (Node* input) {
    Node* cell = new Node;
    cell->amount = input->amount;
    cell->price = input->price;
    cell->next = input->next;
    cell->prev = input->prev;
    return cell;
}
```

push (enqueue) function:

```
void List::push(int amount, double price) {
    Node* cell = new Node;
    cell->amount = amount;
    cell->price = price;
    if(isEmpty()) {
            tail = cell;
    }


    else {
            head->prev = cell;
    }

    cell->next = head;
    head = cell;
```

queueTotal(dequeue) function:

```
double List::queueTotal(int total, double price) {
    Node * cell = new Node;
            this->ListPrint();
    if (isEmpty()) std::cout << "Attempting to dequeue empty queue" << std::endl;
    cell = tail;
    double basis = 0.0;
    double gain = total * price;
    for (int i = 0; total; i++) {

            if(cell->amount > 0) {
                    cell->amount -= 1;
                    total -= 1;
            }
            else {
                    basis += (i * cell->price);
                    i = 0;
                    if(head->next == 0) {
                            head = 0;
                    }

                    else{
                            tail->prev->next = 0;
                    }

                    tail = tail->prev;

            }

    }
    double subtotal = gain - basis;
    totalGain += subtotal;
    return subtotal;

}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: push (enqueue) function: `if(isEmpty()) {
            tail = cell;
    }`. When you push a new data to list, the `head` always `null` and `isEmpty()` function always return true.

Answer (score 0):

In the push function if(isEmpty( ) ) { tail =cell; head=cell; } Because you need to initalize the head